# Amortized analysis (dynamic arrays) - how is the cost of 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 ... 2N = 4N - 1?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

Please do watch 9.30 in the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTl8djZFWE0&t=601s

The tutor has mentioned it to be a geometric progression, but I don't see how that progression directly translates to 2 * 2N - 1?

For a costly array append, we have to double the length of the array. So we get 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 16 -> .... -> 2N. Where N is the length of the array. But how is the cost of this 2 * 2N - 1? It's just confusing, and the tutor doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an approximation using the following formula:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k=2\cdot 2^n-1$$
when $2^n=N$. Therefore, $1+2+4+8+\cdots+2N=4\cdot2^n-1$.

Comment: When you say an approximation, you mean it's not always accurate or equal?

Comment: The formula though for the sum of 2^k, I thought this was the formula we use. sum of 2^k =( 2 ^ n + 1 ) - 1 ?

Comment: Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Both $n$ and $n+1$ are $O(n)$. It doesn't matter.